# relplot hue unable to parse strings it thinks are numeric

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

At least I think this is the issue.
I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = {0: [0.187041, -0.07495, 0.383563, -0.258548, -0.137496],
        1: [0.086416, 0.281447, 0.059027, 0.004486, 0.49186],
        'node_idx': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        'labels': ['tech', 'business', 'tech', 'business', 'business'],
        'on': ['train', 'train', 'train', 'train', 'train'],
        'likelihoods': [0.205434, 0.113467, 0.130263, 0.192061, 0.05352],
        'children': ['-1_0', '-1_1', '-1_0', '-1_15', '-1_1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

          0         1  node_idx    labels     on  likelihoods children
0  0.187041  0.086416         0      tech  train     0.205434     -1_0
1 -0.074950  0.281447         1  business  train     0.113467     -1_1
2  0.383563  0.059027         2      tech  train     0.130263     -1_0
3 -0.258548  0.004486         3  business  train     0.192061    -1_15
4 -0.137496  0.491860         4  business  train     0.053520     -1_1

sns_kwargs = {'hue': 'children', 'hue_norm': (0, 1)}
g = sns.relplot(data=df, x=0, y=1, **sns_kwargs)
```

I want to plot with 0 as the x-axis, and 1 as the y-axis. I call
`g = sns.relplot(data=df, x=0, y=1, **sns_kwargs)`, where
`sns_kwargs = {'hue': 'children', 'hue_norm': (0, 1)}` (there are more kwargs, but these are the only possibly relevant ones)

When I `sns_kwargs` has `hue="labels"`, the plot works fine with no errors. However, when `hue="children"`, I get a big ValueError. It looks like seaborn is trying (and failing) to convert to a numeric type under the hood, but I'm not sure how to force it to plot the same way it plots labels. I've tried casting that column to a string with `df = df.astype({"children": "string"})`, but it didn't work. Any help?

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2315, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "-1_0"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [11], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 sns_kwargs = {'hue': 'children', 'hue_norm': (0, 1)}
----> 2 g = sns.relplot(data=df, x=0, y=1, **sns_kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py:46, in _deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     36     warnings.warn(
     37         "Pass the following variable{} as {}keyword arg{}: {}. "
     38         "From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument "
   (...)
     43         FutureWarning
     44     )
     45 kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46 return f(**kwargs)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\seaborn\relational.py:952, in relplot(x, y, hue, size, style, data, row, col, col_wrap, row_order, col_order, palette, hue_order, hue_norm, sizes, size_order, size_norm, markers, dashes, style_order, legend, kind, height, aspect, facet_kws, units, **kwargs)
    946 # Use the full dataset to map the semantics
    947 p = plotter(
    948     data=data,
    949     variables=plotter.get_semantics(locals()),
    950     legend=legend,
    951 )
--> 952 p.map_hue(palette=palette, order=hue_order, norm=hue_norm)
    953 p.map_size(sizes=sizes, order=size_order, norm=size_norm)
    954 p.map_style(markers=markers, dashes=dashes, order=style_order)

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py:53, in SemanticMapping.map(cls, plotter, *args, **kwargs)
     50 def map(cls, plotter, *args, **kwargs):
     51     # This method is assigned the __init__ docstring
     52     method_name = "_{}_map".format(cls.__name__[:-7].lower())
---> 53     setattr(plotter, method_name, cls(plotter, *args, **kwargs))
     54     return plotter

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_core.py:108, in HueMapping.__init__(self, plotter, palette, order, norm)
    100 # Our goal is to end up with a dictionary mapping every unique
    101 # value in `data` to a color. We will also keep track of the
    102 # metadata about this mapping we will need for, e.g., a legend
    103 
    104 # --- Option 1: numeric mapping with a matplotlib colormap
    106 if map_type == "numeric":
--> 108     data = pd.to_numeric(data)
    109     levels, lookup_table, norm, cmap = self.numeric_mapping(
    110         data, palette, norm,
    111     )
    113 # --- Option 2: categorical mapping using seaborn palette

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py:184, in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    182 coerce_numeric = errors not in ("ignore", "raise")
    183 try:
--> 184     values, _ = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
    185         values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
    186     )
    187 except (ValueError, TypeError):
    188     if errors == "raise":

File ~\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\lib.pyx:2357, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "-1_0" at position 0
```

Comment: Using `hue_norm` implies numeric mapping, so this can't work neither for `labels` nor for `children`. Are you sure that this very example works for `{'hue': 'labels', 'hue_norm': (0, 1)}`?

Comment: Ah. I think that was the issue. I wasn't using `hue_norm`  for `hue=labels`. I'll try changing that -- thanks!